# Identify book: Older generation of reptile warriors are awakened from stasis to fight next war until newer generation arrives

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title to a book. It may even have been a short story. In it, Reptile warriors from a previous war are awakened from stasis and thrust into battle as shock troops until an army of more modern troops can be brought to bear. I probably read it in the mid 80s or early 90's. It is Scifi. The warrior-class reptiles were frozen by their own people. As the combat trained survivors of a previous war they readily accept their role as first response troops in the war they are awakened to fight. I think it was written from the warriors point of view. Can anybody help me and name it?

Comment: Could you tell us more? Can you hazard a guess at period of publication? Fantasy or Scifi? Were the reptiles slaves or the dominant race and did they freeze their own warriors?

Comment: This sounds vaguely similar to a Doctor Who episode.

Comment: Definately not part of a series..at least not at the time I read it.

Comment: That rings a bell somewhere in the dark. I can remember something similar, but can't quite place it anywhere. Though, I'm pretty sure it was something on TV what I saw.

Comment: Uh, now I remember what I meant! It was actually a quest from the game 'Neverwinter Nights' about 'The Creator Race', a reptile like race which held humans as slaves (I think)...was a little bit off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it [The Bug Wars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441073735) by Robert Asprin?

The protagonist is awakened to fight once more in a long war of reptiles vs a coalition of insect enemies. He and his team are stranded on an enemy planet during an attack. Later on the protagonist gets promoted to the point where he's a general planning the final assault on the Ants, the smartest enemy race.

Comment: Nice work! That's it!

Comment: Turns out it was a "Teaser" chapter at the end of one of the "Phule" book series. Time to hit the used book store for the whole read.

Comment: It's a decent book, although slim (and a very quick read). :) Glad I could help.